# KVM & Docker is network error when are running at the same time

Tags: docker, kvm

I have docker and kvm running on my ubuntu. A kvm network error occurs when the container is run.

---

[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host ' ~ '"

```
 [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Comment: can you install package using apt-get and can you ping and DNS address?

Comment: No..I can't but, PIng & DNS run when I turn off docker.